# ftp download error in my python script

Tags: python, ftp, md5sum

```
#print "Enter the server name \n"
server = "x.x.x.x"
#ftp = ftplib.FTP(server)
#print "Enter the USN /PWD"
path = raw_input ("Enter the path \n")    
ftp = ftplib.FTP(server,'xxx','yyy')
ftp.cwd(path)
fname = raw_input("Enter the Fname \n")
with open(fname) as file_to_check:
    #read content of the file
    csv1 = file_to_check.read()
    #pipe the contents of the file through
    md5_original = hashlib.md5(csv1).hexdigest()
localfile = open(fname, 'wb')
ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + fname, localfile.write, 512)
print "Done ...."  
ftp.quit()
curpath = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(curdir)
with open(localfile) as file_to_check:
    #read content of the file
    csv2 = file_to_check.read()
    #pipe the contents of the file through
    md5_download = hashlib.md5(csv2).hexdigest()
# Finally compare original MD5 with freshly calculated
if orginal_md5 == md5_returned:
    print "MD5 verified."
else:
    print "MD5 verification failed!."
```

When I run this program, \i got following error at line of ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + fname, localfile.write, 1024)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 401, in retrbinary
data = conn.recv(blocksize)
socket.error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

I dont know what went wrong. please help me to sort out

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?  Having similar issue with pulling a 2GB file off FTP to an Azure VM via Python